# initLoader one after another in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have a fragment that need to loader 7 loaders

in the onActivityCreate();

i call initLoader for all of them .

```
public void onActivityCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){

LoaderManager mgr = getLoaderManager();

mgr.initLoader(0,null,mLoaderCallback0);
mgr.initLoader(1,null,mLoaderCallback1);
mgr.initLoader(2,null,mLoaderCallback2);
mgr.initLoader(3,null,mLoaderCallback3);
mgr.initLoader(4,null,mLoaderCallback4);
mgr.initLoader(5,null,mLoaderCallback5);
mgr.initLoader(6,null,mLoaderCallback6);
}
```

how can i load them efficiently one by one for memory concerns  ,

What i was thinking about

is to loader the first loader in `onActivityCreated` method 
and inside the `onLoadFinished` of it callback i load the second loader and in the second `onLoadFinished` i `initLoader` the third and so on. 
is it good ? or i miss something regards to fragment life cycle.

```
    private LoaderCallbacks<UserFriendResponse> mFirstCallbacks = new LoaderCallbacks<UserFriendResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<UserFriendResponse> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Type1> arg0,
                Type1 arg1) {
....
...
..
if(isAdded()){
getLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,mLoaderCallback1);
}


        }

        @Override
        public Loader<Type1> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
            return new CustomLoader(getActivity(), false, true, false, "1",
                    1, username);
        }
    };
```

**Note : i can't have one callback because each loader return different data type .**

Comment: even though your loaders return different data you still can have one lcallback

Comment: really ? please tell me how?

Comment: When i used multiple CursorLoader i could use on Callback sine all of them return the same data type .but i don't know if you are right in my case

Comment: what about android.app.LoaderManager
.LoaderCallbacks<Object>?

Comment: very nice strongly typed answer .. thanks a lot !

Comment: @user4o01 Were you able to solve this problem ?